# How can I load all the functions of an so file from rust?

Tags: php, rust, shared-libraries

As a personal project to learn Rust I am making a PHP interpreter. I'm still quite far from finishing it, but during the process I wonder how I am going to implement being able to add extensions. I want to leave the last option to also rewrite the PHP libraries, although if there is no other option I think I will have do it. In my project I have this enum representing any PHP data type (the enum has more variants in my project, but I will keep it simple to give the idea):

```
pub enum PhpValue {
    String(String),
    Int(i32),
}
```

How I think I could do it is that based on a file I read all its functions, and I don't know if I could somehow inspect that function to know if they return an int, a string, or if they need a string or int as a parameter , and even get the names of its parameters. I don't know much about how php handles this natively, so my approach is most likely not correct. But I would like if you could tell me what the correct approach would be to do this or some example of how I could do something similar to this.

The only thing I found related to it is [this library](https://docs.rs/libloading/latest/libloading/), but it doesn't seem to suit my needs since to obtain the function I have to know the form and name of the function, so I couldn't do it dynamically.

Comment: A `.so` file is a *shared object* in the [ELF format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format). You could read it in Rust with a parser like the [elf crate](https://crates.io/crates/elf) provides. However, the format doesn't provide the *signatures* of functions (unless you look at debug info which is not guaranteed and may be in a variety of formats). Usually extension systems are not done like this and instead use predefined functions that the host would load and call to see what the extension provides.